# Gatling Runtime Exception from Jenkins :java.io.IOException .. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: exception, jenkins, gatling

I Get the below exception while I run the Gatling(version 2.2.5) Test through a Jenkins Job at 5 TPS -  `rampUsersPerSec(0.1) to 5 during(5 minutes),constantUsersPerSec(5) during(15 minutes)`, the exception starts after 15 mins of test run.

However, I do not see this exception while the test runs at 0.2 TPS - `rampUsersPerSec(0.1) to 0.2 during(5 minutes),constantUsersPerSec(0.2) during(15 minutes)`

The Jenkins( version 2.66 ) runs on Windows 7(64-bit OS), with 4 GB RAM on Tomcat.

Will this be the limitation and cause for this exception? 
what's triggering this, how do I get this resolved ? 
Is there any Gatling Jenkins Host(Load Generator) specification that I have to look for ?

Appreciate your inputs  !

```
22:20:28.946 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.AsyncHandler - Request
T013_GET_Updates' failed for user 601
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:221)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:899)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the port you are using is already occupied. Take specific port for host or remote machine.
Cheers,
Peekay